# How to join oracle tables (apex) with ArcMap?

Tags: oracle-apex, arcmap

Helooo everyone
I'd like to design an oracle (apex) database that is linked to ArcMap, or vice versa, so that the data is synchronized
I tried to link to oracle through ArcMap, but I did not get any results, as shown in the picture.

Thanks to all

[Database connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGlB8.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The message complaints about the Oracle client. In the machine that you are running ArcMap, you need an Oracle client to connect to your database. The client should allow you to connect to your DB directly through SQLplus.